# How to upload localization assets in Hygraph?

Tags: hygraph

We're spent a couple of days searching the way to upload "locale" assets to Hygprah (formerly GrpahCMS).

We have a website to update a FAQ's document, but we need to upload an English and a Spanish version.

Currently, we can upload an asset with the website documentation code-example, but can't find the documentation or an online example to show how to upload 2 assets for different localizations.